# How do I JSON serialize a Python dictionary?

Tags: django, json, serialization

I'm trying to make a Django function for JSON serializing something and returning it in an `HttpResponse` object.

```
def json_response(something):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", something)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

I'm using it like this:

```
return json_response({ howdy : True })
```

But I get this error:

```
"bool" object has no attribute "_meta"
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the traceback:

http://dpaste.com/38786/

Comment: Without the actual traceback, no.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Update: Python now has its own json handler, simply use `import json` instead of using `simplejson`.

---

The Django serializers module is designed to serialize Django ORM objects. If you want to encode a regular Python dictionary you should use simplejson, which ships with Django in case you don't have it installed already.

```
import json

def json_response(something):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(something))
```

I'd suggest sending it back with an application/javascript Content-Type header (you could also use application/json but that will prevent you from debugging in your browser):

```
import json

def json_response(something):
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(something),
        content_type = 'application/javascript; charset=utf8'
    )
```

Comment: Use <a href="https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869">JSONView</a> in Firefox to nicely format JSON returned with the application/json content type.

Comment: That was supposed to be a link to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869

Comment: that plugin is also available in chrome

Comment: you can use import json instead of simplejson

Comment: Adding to @radtek comment, simplejson is deprecated and Django itself now uses the built-in json module. https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/issues/106

Comment: omg thank you, I've spent so long trying to get my JSON to display with indents. I was using HttpResponse but not specifying the content-type. You're a gem thanks again

Answer (score 34):

What about a **JsonResponse** *Class* that extends **HttpResponse**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson

class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data):
        content = simplejson.dumps(data,
                                   indent=2,
                                   ensure_ascii=False)
        super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(content=content,
                                           mimetype='application/json; charset=utf8')
```

Answer (score 15):

With newer versions of Django you can just use JsonResponse provided by django.http:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_view(request):
    json_object = {'howdy': True}
    return JsonResponse(json_object)
```

You can find more details in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

Answer (score 6):

In python 2.6 and higher there is a nice [JSON library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), which has many functions among which is [json.dumps()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) which serializes an object into a string.

So you can do something like this:

```
import json
print json.dumps({'howdy' : True })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

my_list = range(1,10) # a list from 1 to 10

with open('theJsonFile.json', 'w') as file_descriptor:

         json.dump(my_list, file_descriptor) #dump not dumps, dumps = dump-string
```