# Django error serilaizing output of query into JSON

Tags: django, json

Hi
I am trying to use Django to make a page that will search a database fro a certain keyword, I have managed to search the database for the keyword, but now I need to serialize the data into a JSON formatted array so I can use it on the client side using JavaScript.

When I try to serialize my result array I get this error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

My code looks like this:

```
def SearchItems(request, itemName):
    items_list = list(Item.objects.filter(name = itemName).values())

    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    data = json_serializer.serialize(items_list, ensure_ascii=False)

    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
RayQuang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using serializer, trying doing this:

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(items_list),'application/json'))
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798111/how-do-i-json-serialize-a-python-dictionary) for more info

Answer (score 0):

do not convert an object to the dict.
simply pass a queryset to the serializer:

```
json_serializer.serialize(Item.objects.filter(name=itemName), ensure_ascii=False)
```

alternatively, you can use json/cjson/anyjson serializer directly:

```
import anyjson
HttpResponse(anyjson.serialize(Item.objects.filter(name=itemName).values()), content_type="application/json")
```