# incorrect json mimetype?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json, simplejson

I have followed this [How do I JSON serialize a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798111/how-do-i-json-serialize-a-python-dictionary) and this [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) to create a json response like this:

```
def json_response(something):
    return HttpResponse(
        simplejson.dumps(something),
        content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    )
```

How ever I have two complains:

a) When I hit my ajax URL directly in Google Chrome, Inspector says

> Resource interpreted as Document but
>   transferred with MIME type
>   application/json.

also tried Firefox and it gets as a file to download.

b) When I use `jQuery.ajax` works only if I don't pass the dataType argument, if I put for example dataType:'json' then I get this error on jquery.js file

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   :

What am I doing bad?

I am using jquery 1.5.2 and Django Trunk (r15915 updated about two weeks ago) and calling only same domain urls.

EDIT: 
jQuery.getJSON does not work, but worked on jquery 1.4.2.
Looking firebug console on Request Headers says Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode, this may be related to the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug with jquery validate plugin, updating to most recent version solved the problem.

More info about the issue here:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/getjson-and-jquery-1-5

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, when you visit a JSON URL, some browsers treat it as text/html, while others treat it as an external file type.  You can use an add-on like [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/).
2. This should work fine, even though it's redundant.  It sounds like a typo.  You should also double-check with [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) that your JSON document is valid.

Comment: I have already used JSONLint and marks valid, the strange is that I can't use jQuey.getJSON function... I need to use jQuery.ajax without using dataType.