# How to return a list object in httpresponse Django

Tags: django

Does anyone know how to return a list object when you do HttpResponse.

I have tried

```
HttpResponse(['a'.'b'])
```

but this obviously doesn't work.

I have also tried the following

```
return HttpResponse(Context(['a','b']),mimetype='text/plain')
```

but this returns some extra thing which i dont want

```
['a', 'b']{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}
```

i just want it to return

```
['a', 'b']
```

Thanks

Comment: But what are you trying for? are you trying to return a json? a html?

Comment: i want to return a list which has many json objects in it

Comment: You won't be able to return a Python list object though.

Comment: ok thanks i will do it another way then :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/798205/2108339

Answer (score 6):

This should do it for you

```
from django.utils import simplejson
json_stuff = simplejson.dumps({"list_of_jsonstuffs" : ["a", "b"]})    
return HttpResponse(json_stuff, content_type ="application/json")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HttpResponse subclass: JsonResponse.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

For your instance:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse(['a', 'b'], safe=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi this one will work:

your views :

```
 import json
 from django.http import HttpResponse

 def function(request):
     your_list = ['a', 'b']
     your_list_as_json = json.dumps(your_list)
     return HttpResponse(your_list_as_json)
```

Thank you for checking.

Answer (score -2):

Use comma (`,`), and not dot (`.`) to separate list elements, i.e:

```
return HttpResponse("['a', 'b']")
```